# Split list of li into column with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the IE family doesn't accept CSS3 column properties, I'm trying to split a list of `li` into 5 columns with javascript/jquery. In the process, I was told that looping an array backward is faster than looping it normally. I've tried it but it gives me a funny results. The last column is appearing as the 1st column, which I don't want. I don't know what's wrong with the code. On top, the code reads slow in browser... Please give me some light.

JS/jQuery:

```
var JL = {}, JL.Module = {};

JL.Module.indexSort = function(){
  var indexContainers = $('.index-section'),
      indexControls = $('ul.index-navigation li'),
      ieIndexContainers = $('.ie6, .ie7, .ie8, .ie9').find('.index-section'),
      ulWrap = '<ul class="new-col" />',
      colCount = 5,
      subLi;

  indexContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

  indexControls.filter(':first').addClass('selected');

  //IE family don't accept css columns properties, so have to use JS
  ieIndexContainers.each(function () {  
     var thisElem = $(this),
         indexUl = thisElem.find('ul'),
         indexLi = thisElem.find('li'),
         indexLiLen = indexLi.length,
         liPerCol = Math.ceil(indexLiLen / colCount),
         lastColCount = indexLiLen % liPerCol,
         sliceStart = indexLiLen - lastColCount,
         sliceEnd = indexLiLen,
         subLi,
         i;

     ieIndexContainers.find('ul').addClass('new-col');

     setTimeout(function(){
        sliceEnd = 0;
        sliceStart = -1;

        // Looping the array backwards
        for(i = colCount - 1; i > 0; i--){
            sliceEnd = sliceStart;
            sliceStart = (sliceEnd - liPerCol >= 0) ? sliceEnd - liPerCol : 0;
            subLi = indexLi.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd);
            indexUl.after($(ulWrap).append(subLi));

        }

        ieIndexContainers.find('.new-col').show();

      }, 0);

  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="s" class="index-section">
  <h2>s</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Aorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Apsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Aonor</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Asdijnd oasd</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Awrom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Aoidn iojd</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Asddewdwe</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Apsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Aonor</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Asdijnd oasd</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Awrom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Aoidn iojd</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Asddewdwe</a></li>          
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Iterating through an array in reverse is the micro-optimisation of all micro-optimisations. You're talking microseconds.

Comment: Also, you're using jQuery, which is going to cause a lot more overhead on its own than iterating an array backwards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop it forward. The being slower relates to not caching the array's length. However, you do cache the upper bound of the for-loop in `colCount`. Don't worry about performance, just do the loop the right way around. Let it count forward.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you need to update your for loop:

```
// Looping the array backwards         
for(i = colCount - 1; i > 0; i--){             
  sliceEnd = sliceStart;             
  sliceStart = (sliceEnd - liPerCol >= 0) ? sliceEnd - liPerCol : 0;             
  subLi = indexLi.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd);             
  indexUl.after($(ulWrap).append(subLi));     
}
```

should be:

```
// Looping the array backwards         
for(i = colCount - 1; i >= 0; i--){             
  sliceEnd = sliceStart;             
  sliceStart = (sliceEnd - liPerCol >= 0) ? sliceEnd - liPerCol : 0;
  subLi = indexLi.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd);             
  indexUl.after($(ulWrap).append(subLi));     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should perform the slice, *then* adjust the new sliceEnd and sliceStart:

```
for (i = colCount - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    subLi = indexLi.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd);
    indexUl.after($(ulWrap).append(subLi));
    sliceEnd = sliceStart;
    sliceStart = (sliceEnd - liPerCol >= 0) ? sliceEnd - liPerCol : 0;
}
```

This will fix your column ordering problem. No comments on array looping forward/backward.